# Chew longer before swallow

Tags: grammar, emphasis

How do I tell a kid to chew his food longer time and into smaller pieces before he swallow it.

> "Bite longer before swallow."
>
> "Chew longer before swallow."

Comment: Did you check a dictionary bite vs. chew?

Comment: @user3169 I know the different. Just wonder what word will suitable for kid because they are still very young.

Comment: My mother told me to *chew each bite* 10 times! It has both - chew and bite! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Chew longer before swallow**ing**.

is the correct phrase, but often a child will not know what "*longer*" may mean, so it might be better to say

> Chew your food 25 times before swallowing.

assuming they can count to 25, but it would also be a way for them to learn how to count to 25.

Good luck!

Comment: It may also be a way for them to learn that sometimes adults give meaningless and arbitrary instruction. It's hard for me to imagine a child that knows 25 but doesn't know "longer".

Comment: My point was that to a child, 5 or 10 might be considered "longer", if an adult merely says "longer".